# Don't know how to toggle display whilst switching routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been quite frustrated for about 3 hours now as I want to toggle between routes. Here's what I mean

Server Template HTML:

```html
<!-- When the component first opens, I want this first div to display. Howeever, when I click the button
     I want it to disapper and router-outlet to show up. When I change servers, I want 'display' to be true -->
<div *ngIf="display">
    <h5>{{ server.name }}</h5>
<p>Server status is {{ server.status }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit Server</button>
</div>

<!-- When I change servers, this whole template disappears. -->
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Server Component TS:

```js
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  id: number
  display: boolean = true
  URLid: number

  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    // This just captures the id in the url and it searches for its respective server
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id)
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id)
    })
  }

  onEdit() {
    /* 
      When the button is clicked, display is set to false. This in turn, makes it so only 'router-outlet'
      is displayed. However, when the server is changed, everything disappears.
    */
    this.display = !this.display
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.URLid = params['id']
    })
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route})

  }

}
```

EditServer Template:

```html
<h4>No editing the server!</h4>
```

All other code is irrelevent.

In case pictures help, I'll provide pictures as well.

(1) Initial State of the problem
[image]

(2) When I press Edit Server, it works as I wanted.
[image]

(3) When I change the server to `Devserver` for example, it will be blank. But I want it to reset to (1).
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the complete project ( may be a quick stackblitz ) ? It will be quick that way for me to assist.

Comment: My guess is, that your routing on the server list is wrong. How does the routing look like here?

Comment: @Yousef when you click the second time, maybe you navigate to `edit` relative to the route which already includes `edit`? Anyway demonstrate your issue on Stackblitz for effective help

Comment: @Benny , I am sorry I don't know how to use stackblitz but I did make a GitHub repository for this. Ignore the "home" & "users" folder as they are not relevent. The only relevent ones are the app component, AppModule, and servers folder. You can simulate the project with the github, and hopefully the problem will be clear. https://github.com/yousefmarey12/stackblitz-starters-6l5ddr.git

Comment: @HarshSingla , I am sorry I don't know how to use stackblitz but I did make a GitHub repository for this. Ignore the "home" & "users" folder as they are not relevent. The only relevent ones are the app component, AppModule, and servers folder. You can simulate the project with the github, and hopefully the problem will be clear. https://github.com/yousefmarey12/stackblitz-starters-6l5ddr.git

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I sent the routing on Github. Check the previous comments, and it will be in the AppModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to follow your nested logic. However, changing as follows achieves what you expect (if I understand correctly):

In **edit-server.component.ts** method `OnInit`:

```
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id);

      // Add this line to reset display to true when selecting another server from the list
      this.display = true;
    });
```